# How can I use a different object manager for related models?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have a couple of classes:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    address = models.ForeignKey(Address, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Address(LiveModel):
    address = models.CharField(max_length=512)

    some_manager = SomeManager()
    some_other_object_manager = OtherManager()

    class Meta:
        base_manager_name = 'some_other_object_manager'
```

Because I set `some_manager`, the default manager used is `SomeManager` which is good.  BUT if I am querying a `Person`, I want it to use `Address`'s `OtherManager` manager for querying and I thought that by setting `base_manager_name`, I would be able to achieve this (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/managers/#using-managers-for-related-object-access).  Unfortunately this does not work.  Any ideas?   Particularly I am trying to achieve this in the admin, if that makes a difference.

Comment: I set up a similar POC and it worked fine for me. Perhaps you could share a bit more of your code. Particularly what query didn't work, and what you expected, and perhaps the Manager definitions as well?

Comment: @Shane I will add a bit more detail to start and see how it goes.  So when I am in the admin change form for `Person`, I'll add a person, select an address from the drop down and save.  Then I go and edit my address and I have a field called `soft_delete`, I'll set that to true and save.  When I go back to the change form for `Person`, it's using `some_manager` to populate the address drop down which does not include soft deleted record so the address is not there.  I want it to use `some_other_object_manager` which does include soft deleted records.

Comment: @Shane you are right, if I write a script with the query, my example does work on getting the related object.  I think I just assumed that it would use a relationship off of `Person` to populate its address in the drop down.  It clearly does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clarify, this does work as intended.  The issue here was in the detail.  I was using the Django admin which does not query the related fields the way I expected. It actually uses the related fields `default manager` for the `queryset`.  If you want to do what I am trying to do, this is a nice simple example: https://books.agiliq.com/projects/django-admin-cookbook/en/latest/filter_fk_dropdown.html